# How to secure backend API calls (backend server is on-premise) of a Mobile App via AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cognito

My mobile app needs to make secure API calls to  on-premise backend services which is not exposed to internet but accessed only by mobile client. How can we secure the backend calls via AWS cloud?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If your backend API is not exposed to the internet, how can any client, let alone a mobile one, make a call against it?

Comment: On-premises services must be accessible only to the mobile clients.I plan to go for SNS for mobile push notification. So can I have a solution for securing API in AWS cloud itself?

Answer (score 0):

AWS does not have an out-of-the-box solution for what you are looking for. Amazon Cognito's Identity component was designed to secure access to AWS API's, not a developer's. You will have to build your authentication and authorization service for your mobile clients.

Another AWS technology that you may want to consider in your design is [Amazon Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)](http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/), which would allow you to bridge your on-premise network into the AWS cloud. From their you would have to properly secure systems and APIs.

**Update 2015-07-09** AWS has announced [Amazon API Gateway](http://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/). Using API Gateway you can build a REST interface to your existing API (or to AWS Lamdba functions) secured with credentials retrieved via an Amazon Cognito authflow. See [this blog post](http://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) for additional announcement details.